# How to receive parameters in Web API controller from post method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Net based application using Web api and angularjs. I am trying to integrate payment API's. The post variables can be accessed on the redirect URL.

I am able to receive in asp.net as below.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string order_id = Request.Form["order_id"];
            string transaction_id = Request.Form["transaction_id"];
        }
```

I want to receive parameters in Webapi2. Is there any way i can write above piece of code in api? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post your data from AngularJs app to Web API using the $http.post method.

```
var data = {
    orderId: your_order_id,
    transactionId: your_transactio_id
};

$http
    .post("/api/token", data)
    .then(onSuccess, onError);
```

If you are passing data in post inside body, you should be able to receive the data using

```
public bool Post(PostParameters parameters)
{
    var orderId = parameters.OrderId;
    var transactionId = parameters.TransactionId;
}
```

Where PostParamaters is just a plain class with the properties you want to pass. Of course, your data types can be different.

```
public class PostParameters
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
}
```